# Answers deleted as result of a DMCA Takedown Request still visible via revision history

Tags: bug, status-review, revisions-list, copyright-infringement

This is a follow-up to [Posts deleted as result of a DMCA Takedown Request still visible via suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391773/295232). If you have 10k+ reputation on Stack Overflow, you can see the [revision history of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16620665/revisions) has been erased:

> This question was removed due to a DMCA takedown and is therefore not shown.

[image]

On the Q&A page, the answers are erased as well:

> This answer was removed due to a DMCA takedown on the parent question and is therefore not shown.

(unlike answers to deleted questions, those have the same banner "This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted last month along with its parent question." but their content is shown)

[image]

However, the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17623252/revisions) still works:

[image]

Comment: I thought that they would use the redaction tool for this. The downside (pointed out under another question) is that OP will have a very hard time fighting the DMCA if they can't even see what content got removed.

Comment: We are aware of this bug and are working on a fix. I added the [tag:status-review] tag and will post an update as an answer once the changes are in :)