# Possible bug - Deleted question keeps reappearing for review

Tags: bug, review, deleted-questions

The question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35682256

If you try to do anything with it:

> This post was removed due to a DMCA takedown and is not accepting new reviews.

And yet it keeps reappearing as a question that needs to be reviewed. Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Utterly nothing in that question seems to require a “DMCA Takedown Request.”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Perhaps it was a verbatim copy/paste from a textbook of some sort. A quick Google search offers this as one of the results: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-string-mathrm-s-length-mathrm-n-consisting-letters-mathrm-b--goal-obtain-string-form-q101858994

Comment: And it appeared again for some reason, after 5-10 regular first questions.

Comment: Odd. What is Chegg? Could it be a Stack Overflow scraper? Or just a site accumulating homework and related answers?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Wikipedia says this: "Chegg, Inc., is an American education technology company based in Santa Clara, California. It provides homework help, digital and physical textbook rentals, textbooks, online tutoring, and other student services" . That could explain the takedown.

Comment: Ahhh! Homework pirates issue a takedown! We have come a long way from this guy I knew who sold tests and term papers from the 3rd floor bathroom in college in the 1990s! Yes, seriously. His “take down” notice was his fists.

Comment: This bug was already reported on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428213/

Comment: @janw Is it possible to somehow close this one as a duplicate? I tried flagging it (since it seems I can't close it on my own), but the duplicate is on meta.stackoverflow.com, and I can't really flag it.

Comment: Unfortunately not, @FiddlingAway, as (as you already noted) the duplicate is on another site. We could (ab)use the "Relates only to one specific site" close reason, or just let the question exist for reference in case the problem occurs on another site.

Comment: @janw Found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391773/posts-deleted-as-result-of-a-dmca-takedown-request-still-visible-via-suggested-e). Flagged myself as a duplicate, since the linked question is about the same thing, essentially.

Comment: The reason is that they don't delete such posts, but rather only **marking** them, and it only affects very few places, e.g. the post itself when viewing the question page itself and maybe revisions. All the rest places will still show the contents because, well, nobody wrote the code to hide it in there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda What had me confused - the question can't be reviewed, since it was taken down, and yet it keeps reappearing as a question that needs to be reviewed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posts deleted as result of a DMCA Takedown Request still visible via suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391773/posts-deleted-as-result-of-a-dmca-takedown-request-still-visible-via-suggested-e)

Comment: @Joachim It does and it doesn't, and I'm conflicted about accepting the prompt asking me for feedback. It does, in the sense that I myself marked this as a duplicate of that particular question, and also it addresses the same issue. Plus, there was a fix in August 2023. But, on the other hand, the deleted question is still popping up for review, which seems to indicate that either the August fix didn't cover this particular case, or there were later changes which undid the fix. I honestly don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @FiddlingAway That's an entirely different bug, and an entirely different cause. Also, even if it were the same, meta policy is that if a bug has been previously reported and fixed but has come up again, a new report should be filed.

Answer (score 4):

This odd bug has already been reported on Meta Stack Overflow:

- [DMCA deleted question still reviewable and displays original content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428213)

Setting as an answer since we can’t flag as dupe across sites.